# Power BI applying a local filter to one field, which filters another - without the restrictions/ filters of the initial filter

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I’m looking to apply a local, custom filter to a single field, which will be used to filter another field – without it filtering all subsequent data within Power BI.

The use case is that I am ultimately trying to work with an inventory file to see which suppliers provide products in certain categories/ subcategories as a selected supplier.
The hierarchy of search would be:

1. See all categories/ subcategories that a chosen supplier provides
   products in (i.e., filtered by supplier)
2. See all products (SKUs) from all suppliers in those categories/ subcategories (i.e., no
   filter on this data)

I’ve been able to use a DAX query to filter based on a flag (i.e., is ‘supplier code’ the code of interest) but then it seems to filter everything else.